# Find the sum of $-1^2-2^2+3^2+4^2-5^2-6^2+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation

> Find the sum of $$\sum_{k=1}^{4n}(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}k^2$$

By expanding the given summation,

$$\sum_{k=1}^{4n}(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}k^2=-1^2-2^2+3^2+4^2-5^2-6^2+\cdots+(4n-1)^2+(4n)^2$$
$$=(3^2-1^2)+(4^2-2^2)+(7^2-5^2)+(8^2-6^2)+\cdots+[(4n-1)^2-(4n-3)^2]+((4n)^2-(4n-2)^2)$$
$$=2(4)+2(6)+2(12)+2(14)+2(20)+2(22)+\cdots+2(8n-4)+2(8n-2)$$
$$=2[4+6+12+14+20+22+\cdots+(8n-4)+(8n-2)]$$
How should I proceed further?

Comment: Write the last step in summation notation.

Comment: @mlainz there is an increase of 6 after every two terms

Comment: @Aditya: Experiment a little. There’s only one natural way to split a series of $2n$ terms into two series of $n$ terms each, and it happens to work.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Is it (4,12,20,...) and (6,14,22,...)?

Comment: @Aditya: It is indeed. And you shouldn’t have much trouble verifying that this split always *does* give you two arithmetic progressions with constant different $8$.

Comment: Note that pairing from beginning and end $(4n+1)(4n-1)+(4n+1)(4n-3)-(4n+1)(4n-5)-\dots$ gives an obvious factor of $4n+1$ which should appear in the answer and this can be used as a check. This also provides an alternative first step to a solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT: Split your last sum into the sum of two arithmetic progressions, each of length $n$.

An alternative is to calculate a few values of the sum, guess a closed form, and then prove the closed form. For $n=1,2,3$ the sum in question is $20,72,156$, respectively. Note that $20=4\cdot5$, $72=8\cdot9$, and $156=12\cdot 13$.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: except $-1^2$ make pairs of other terms: $$-1^2+(-2^2+3^2)+(4^2-5^2)+(-6^2+7^2)+....$$ and then proceed further to get $-1^2+2+3+4+5+6+...$ and than solve it to get the result

Answer (score 2):

$
=2[4+6+12+14+20+22+\cdots+(8n-4)+(8n-2)]
\\ = 4[(2+3)+(6+7)+(10+11)+\cdots+(8n-3)]
\\ = 4[5+13+21+\cdots+(8n-3)]
\\ = 4 \sum_{k=1}^n (8k-3)
\\ = 4 (4n^2+n)
\\ = 16n^2+4n
$

Answer (score 1):

We know that $$\begin{align*}1+2+3+...+(4n+1)&=\frac{(4n+1) \cdot (4n+2)}{2}\\&=(2n+1)(4n+1)\end{align*}$$
So, $$\begin{align*}&2+3+(2+2)+(3+2)+6+7+...+(4n-2)+(4n-1)+(4n-2+2)+(4n-1+2)=(2n+1)(4n+1)-1 \\&\implies 2(2+3+...(4n-1))+2n \cdot 2=(2n+1)(4n+1)-1 \\&\implies 2(4+6+6+7+...+(8n-2))=2((2n+1)(4n+1)-4n-1)\\&=16n^2+4n\\&=\fbox{4n(4n+1)}\end{align*}$$

This is what you need.

Comment: This is a bit hard to read. Could you try using "begin{align}" to improve formatting?

Comment: @BigbearZzz I don't have much experience in Latex. It'd be great if you could help.

Comment: @BigbearZzz I tried my best. :)

Comment: I'd suggest you this page http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference , it helped me a lot when I started learning it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the last line what you have enclosed into rectangular braces, namely $S$, can be rearranged as follows

\begin{align*}
S&=(1+3)+(2+4)+(5+7)+(6+8)+(9+11)+(10+12)+\cdots+[(4n-3)+(4n-1)]+[(4n-2)+4n]\\
&=\sum_{j=1}^{4n}j\\[3pt]
&=\frac{4n(4n+1)}{2}\\[3pt]
&=\boxed{\color{blue}{2n(4n+1)}}
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{4n}(-1)^{\frac{k(k+1)}{2}}k^2 &= \sum_{k=1}^{n}[((4k - 1)^2 - (4k - 3)^2) + ((4k)^2 - (4k - 2)^2)]\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{n}[2(8k - 4) + 2(8k - 2)] \\
&= 4\sum_{k=1}^{n}[(8k - 3)] \\
&= -12n + 32\sum_{k=1}^{n}k\\
&= -12n + \frac{32n(n+1)}{2} \\
&= 16n^2 + 4n. \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}