# Find the sum of $1^{n}-2^{n}+3^{n}-4^{n}+\cdots+m^{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, arithmetic, bernoulli-numbers

After seing [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738560/find-the-sum-of-12-223242-52-62-cdots) I started wondering about a generalization of a similar sum. The sum is
$$
S(m,n)=\sum_{r=1}^{m}(-1)^{r-1}\;r^{n}
$$

I gave this to WA to crunch and it gave 
$$
S(m,n)= (-1)^{m}2^{n}\left(\zeta\left(-n, \frac{m+2}{2}\right)-\zeta\left(-n,\frac{m+1}{2}\right) \right)-(2^{n}-1)\zeta(-n)
$$

I know that Bernoully numbers,$B_{n}$, and Bernoully polynomials, $B_{n+1}(x)$,  are involved expressing
$$
\zeta(-n,x)=-\frac{B_{n+1}(x)}{n+1}\;\;\;and\;\;\;\zeta(-n)=-\frac{B_{n+1}}{n+1}
$$
But I wonder if this expression could, somehow, be simplified to express $S(m,n)$ in a more pleasant way, involving somehow powers of two.

I think that when $m$ is a Mersenne number, i.e. of the form $2^{m}-1$, it will be possible to obtain some kind of oversimplification.

Anyways, what I'm looking for is some other forms to express $S(m,n)$ with a  special interest in the case of the upper limit of the sum being $2^{m}-1$, i.e. in the case
$$
\begin{align*}
S(m,n)&=\sum_{r=1}^{2^{m}-1}(-1)^{r-1}\;r^{n}\\
      &=-2^{n}\left(\zeta\left(-n, \frac{2^{m}+1/2}{2}+\frac{1}{4}\right)-\zeta\left(-n,\frac{2^{m}+1/2}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right) \right)-(2^{n}-1)\zeta(-n)
\end{align*}\\
$$

Thanks is advance.

Comment: One can use Faulhaber's Formula and the fact that we can write $1^n - 2^n + 3^n - 4^n + \cdots \pm m^n$ as $1^n + 2^n + 3^n + 4^n + \cdots + m^n - 2^n \left( 1^n + 2^n + \cdots + \left\lfloor \frac{m}{2} \right\rfloor^n \right)$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $2|m$

Consider our sum
$$S = \sum_{j = 1}^{m}{(-1)^{j + 1}j^{n}} = S(n,m) - 2\sum_{j = 1}^{m/2}{(2\cdot j)^{n}} = S(n,m) - 2\cdot 2^{n}S(n,\frac{m}{2})$$

If $m \equiv1 {\mod{2}} $, then :

$$S = S(n,m) - 2\cdot 2^{n}S(n,\frac{m - 1}{2})$$, actually I don't know what is the better simplification.

UPD: $S(n,m) = \frac{1}{n+1}\sum_{j = 0}^{n} (-1)^{j} \binom{n+1}{j}B_{j}m^{n+1 -j} $