# Sum of alternating sign groups of integer squares

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

This is a generalization of the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1738560/find-the-sum-of-12-223242-52-62-cdots), assuming the sign changes for groups of $k$ consecutive squares. What is the closed form for the summation?

$$-1^2-2^2-3^2-\cdots-k^2+(k+1)^2+\cdots+(2k)^2-(2k+1)^2-\cdots+(2mk)^2\\=\sum_{i=1}^{2m}\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^i\big[(i-1)k+j\big]^2=?$$

*Background*:
Questions have been posted by others previously on the sum of alternating sign squares of integers, which turns out to be $\pm$ the sum of integers. The question in the link is interesting as it is the sum of alternating sign squares grouped in pairs. This leads one to wonder if there is a general form when the alternating sign squares are in groups of $k$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}
&\sum_{i=1}^{2m}\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^i[(i-1)k+j]^2\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^k \big[(2r-2)k+j\big]^2+\big[(2r-1)k+j\big]^2
\qquad\text{(taking terms in pairs)}\\
&=\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^k (4r-3)k^2+2jk\\
&=k^2\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^k(4r-3)+2k\sum_{r=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^kj\\
&=k^3\sum_{r=1}^m(4r-3)+2mk\sum_{j=1}^kj\\
&=m(2m-1)k^3+2mk\cdot \frac{k(k+1)}2\\
&=mk^2(2mk+1)\qquad\blacksquare
\end{align}$$